# Precompile assets from another directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a directory in the root of my Rails app called `/viewer`.

This directory holds some assets which I would want to precompile to a specific `/public/viewer-assets` directory.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Go through this will helping you
https://launchschool.com/blog/rails-asset-pipeline-best-practices

Answer (score 0):

You can add the list of precompile file of Javascrip and CSS under the file `assets.rb` into the initializers. For example you can refer the below code...

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( landing.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( landing.js )
```

Comment: Thanks! I know this, but my specific assets directory lives under /viewer. As in cd project/viewer/css

Comment: So you can add the path to your file.

Comment: If that not work, Then I think you should move all your assets into the folder of vender/assets.

Comment: That will defiantly works, I am doing the same right now and all are working fine in all the modes.